# Table goes out of the half width Layout

Tags: tables, layout

I have the following Layout in my article.

[image]

I've added a table like this

```
  \begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{MINT-Lücke im Vergleich zu den Vorjahren}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c}
    \textbf{} & \textbf{Lücke Oktober 2020} \textbf{Durchschnitt Lücke Obktober-Werte 2014-19} \textbf{Veränderungen in Prozent} \\
        \hline
  MINT gesamt & 108.700 &  235.800 & -53,9 \\
 IT-Berufe & 26.000 & 38.800 & -33,0 \\
Berufe Maschinen/Fahrzeugbau & 26.000 & 42.900 & -89,3 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

**My Question is what can I do that the table takes only the dedicated space?**

Comment: you have specified `c`  columns, so centred text with no line breaking. Try `p{1cm}` or whatever

Comment: Is `\textbf{Lücke Oktober 2020} \textbf{Durchschnitt Lücke Obktober-Werte 2014-19} \textbf{Veränderungen in Prozent}` really supposed to be the column header for a single column or did you actually wanted to use `\textbf{Lücke Oktober 2020} & \textbf{Durchschnitt Lücke Obktober-Werte 2014-19} & \textbf{Veränderungen in Prozent}`?

Comment: I am new to latex and I found this here https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tabularx`-based solution.

[image]

I would strongly recommend that you shorten the material in some of the header cells.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{MINT gesamt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{MINT-Lücke im Vergleich zu den Vorjahren\strut}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} L{\mylen} CCC @{}}
    \toprule
    & Lücke Oktober 2020
    & Durchschnitt Lücke Oktober-Werte 2014--19
    & Veränderungen, in~Prozent \\
    \midrule
 MINT gesamt & 108.700 &  235.800 & $-$53,9 \\ \addlinespace
 IT-Berufe   &  26.000 &   38.800 & $-$33,0 \\ \addlinespace
 Berufe Maschinen\slash Fahrzeugbau & 26.000 & 42.900 & $-$89,3 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion on how to redesign the table to make it fit into one column of a `twocolumn` `article` document. I used `booktabs` for horizontal lines with improved spacing, `\thead` form the `makecell` package for the column headers and the `S` column type from `siunitx` in order to improve the alignment of the numbers in the columns. I also introduced abbreviations and linebreaks in teh column headers to save some space. To fit the table into the available space, I lastly also slightly decreased the value of `\tabcolsep`.

If you need some background info on the purpose of the used packages and commands, feel free to ask.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text. Do not use in real document.
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={.}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

  \begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \caption{MINT-Lücke im Vergleich zu den Vorjahren}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=6]  S[table-format=6]   S[table-format=-2.1]@{}}
    \toprule
     & {\thead{Lücke\\ Okt. 2020}}
       & {\thead{$\diameter$  Lücke \\Okt.-Werte\\ 2014-19}}
         & {\thead{Veränder.\\ in Prozent}} \\
        \midrule
  MINT gesamt & 108700 &  235800 & -53,9 \\
  \addlinespace
 IT-Berufe & 26000 & 38800 & -33,0 \\
 \addlinespace
\makecell[tl]{Berufe\\ Maschinen/\\Fahrzeugbau} & 26000 & 42900 & -89,3 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```